# broken network -- ping works on IP addresses but not on hostnames

Tags: networking, php, owncloud, ping

I did a fresh install of raspbian on an rpi-3 with the intent to follow this [guide to set up an owncloud server](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-owncloud/)
However after some first steps, when I reboot and reconnect I get the strange problem that I cannot connect to any website anymore. I can SSH to fixed IPs but not to hostnames

```
pi@fry:~ $ ping www.google.com
ping: www.google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
pi@fry:~ $ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=60 time=10.1 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=60 time=12.1 ms
```

It seems like somehow there's no DNS .. 
Does anyone have any idea what to do here?

I should perhaps add that one of the first things I do is to configure a static IP

```
interface wlan0
static ip_address=192.168.2.111/24
static routers=192.168.2.254
```

**/etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1     ip6-allnodes
ff02::2     ip6-allrouters

127.0.1.1   fry
```

These are my running services

https://dpaste.de/pirj

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

solved ... Forgot to add DNS to `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`

```
static domain_name_servers=192.168.2.254 8.8.8.8
```